# I created a CSV File using Python. But the size is huge

Tags: python, csv

I have the below code used to create a CSV file:

```
import csv
srcFile = open("C:\Users\XXXX\Expenses.csv","r")
data = srcFile.read()

srcList = data.split("\n")

colNames = srcList[0].split(",")
header = srcList[1]

sheetData = srcList[2:]
final_data = []
expense_data = []

for row in sheetData:
    split_row = row.split(",")
    final_data.append(split_row)

for row in range(0, len(final_data)-1):
    for col in range(3, 30):
        loc = final_data[row][0]
        opsheet = final_data[row][1]
        rowNum = final_data[row][2]
        colName = colNames[col]

        str1 = "='\\\xxxxxxx\xxxx\xxx\[APR_"
        str2 = "_DATA.xlsm]"
        str3 = "\'!"
        str4 = "$"
        finalStr = str1 + loc + str2 + opsheet + str3 + colName + str4 + rowNum
        final_data[row][col] = ""

with open("c:\users\xxxxx\new_expenses.csv", "wb") as f:
    fwriter = csv.writer(f)
    fwriter.writerows(final_data)
```

I'm a beginner in Python and I know this code is not up to the standards or a real way to code. But this code works fine and creates a CSV file.

Now the problem is this file is already created by someone else and I'm replicating it for other purposes with new data and everything. The existing file, created earlier, was only 30MB in size. But the file that is created in this method is 180MB and takes an enormous amount of time to open.

The original file is nothing but a single worksheet with 51,000 rows and 20 Columns each cell referencing to some cell in a workbook in a network location.

Any idea on how to reduce the size? or What is causing the huge?
Also as a beginner, any suggestions/feedback to improving the code is really appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why aren't you using the csv module to read the source file?

Comment: Like I said, I just started(2 days back) learning Python. But thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to explore it. I had to rush things because of urgent need